# DispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors is not available in netstandard2.0

Tags: wcf

I created a netstandard library project, within this project I created a class that implement from `IOperationBehavior`, in the method `ApplyDispatchBehavior` I cannot use `dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors`, it's telling that this collection is not available in netstandard2.0.
I have no idea about this, would everyone advice me? If there are no solution for this, I think I need to downgrade to use .net framework instead.

[https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10347829/91959103-6660f780-ed32-11ea-9a7e-15a5482e7b71.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDJoI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use WCF in core or netstandard2.0 you need to install System.ServiceModel.Primitives:

[image]

To support WCF in core or netstandard, Microsoft provides the following packages:

[image]

**But if you want to use WCF, I suggest you use .net framework.**

Comment: Yes, I've already install System.ServiceModel.Primitives. But there are no way to to do ```dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(this);```

Comment: ``` public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
        {
            dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(this);
        }```

Comment: System.ServiceModel.Primitives does not implement all the classes of WCF, it only implements some of the functions, and netstandard and core cannot create WCF server.

Comment: I decided to use the .net framework. Thanks @Ding Peng